# Synapse Launcher, Segmentation Fault when typing; changing xim output to ibus

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm getting an error, "Segmentation Fault" when I try to type in at the Synapse Launcher.

Very similar to Joe Gibken in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1219314), I tried changing the xim output to ibus but I can't seem change the xim output to ibus when using the Synapse Launcher.

Is there another way to make the Synapse launcher work again?

Using Linux Mint 14 Xfce 64bit